# Dart Json data parsing ,Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

json data

```
 {
 "data": {
  "getJobs": [
  {
    "id": "124",
    "title": "another",
    "addressId": null,
    "status": "OPEN",
    "companyAddress": null,
    "industry": "IT",
    "jobType": "PART_TIME",
    "salaryMin": 10000,
    "salaryMax": 20000,
    "deadline": "2021-04-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "isFeatured": false,
    "description": "test check"
   }
  ]
 }
 }
```

Model class

```
import 'dart:convert';

 GetJobsResponseModel getJobsResponseModelFromJson(String str) => 
GetJobsResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String getJobsResponseModelToJson(GetJobsResponseModel data) => 
json.encode(data.toJson());

class GetJobsResponseModel {
Data? data;

GetJobsResponseModel({
    this.data,
});

factory GetJobsResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => 
 GetJobsResponseModel(
    data: json["data"] == null ? null : Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data?.toJson(),
};
}

class Data {
List<GetJob>? getJobs;

Data({
    this.getJobs,
});

factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    getJobs: json["getJobs"] == null ? [] : List<GetJob>.from(json["getJobs"]!.map((x) 
=> GetJob.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "getJobs": getJobs == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(getJobs!.map((x) => 
x.toJson())),
};
}

class GetJob {
String? id;
String? title;
dynamic addressId;
String? status;
dynamic companyAddress;
String? industry;
String? jobType;
int? salaryMin;
int? salaryMax;
DateTime? deadline;
bool? isFeatured;
String? description;

GetJob({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.addressId,
    this.status,
    this.companyAddress,
    this.industry,
    this.jobType,
    this.salaryMin,
    this.salaryMax,
    this.deadline,
    this.isFeatured,
    this.description,
});

factory GetJob.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetJob(
    id: json["id"],
    title: json["title"],
    addressId: json["addressId"],
    status: json["status"],
    companyAddress: json["companyAddress"],
    industry: json["industry"],
    jobType: json["jobType"],
    salaryMin: json["salaryMin"],
    salaryMax: json["salaryMax"],
    deadline: json["deadline"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["deadline"]),
    isFeatured: json["isFeatured"],
    description: json["description"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "addressId": addressId,
    "status": status,
    "companyAddress": companyAddress,
    "industry": industry,
    "jobType": jobType,
    "salaryMin": salaryMin,
    "salaryMax": salaryMax,
    "deadline": deadline?.toIso8601String(),
    "isFeatured": isFeatured,
    "description": description,
   };
 }
```

Service

```
     Future<List<GetJob>> getAllJobs(){
     try{
      -------
       final data = result.data?['data']['getJobs'] as List;
      final List<GetJob> jobs = data.map((job) => GetJob.fromJson(job)).toList();
      return jobs;

     }
   catch(e){
     print('Error fetching data: $e');
      rethrow; 
  }
```

I am facing this error:-  Error fetching data: Null check operator used on a null value. How to solve it?  It shows empty list. i want to get "id","title", "addressId" etc on ui

i am using this website to generate model https://app.quicktype.io/.  And What is the best way to create model ? could you suggest me good way to create model ?

Comment: please share the rest of getAllJobs() function

Comment: Future<List<GetJob>> getAllJobs() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('api link');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        final data = jsonData['data']['getJobs'] as List;
        final List<GetJob> jobs = data.map((job) => GetJob.fromJson(job)).toList();

        print(' Data: $jobs');
        return jobs;
      } else {
        throw Exception('error ');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching jobs: $e');
      rethrow; 
    }
  }